# Box clones don't move down like originals

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I made a code that generates a couple of random red boxes and they're supposed to move down. The blue box (the player) needs to dodge them using the arrow keys. I made the clones of the red box, but they won't fall down like the original red box. There is only 1 box that falls down, and thats the original red box.
Also, when the collision occurs, the screen changes, but the game doesn't end.

This is my code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import turtle
import random
import time
import sys
width = 800
height = 600
player_x = 100 #player x
player_y = 0 #player y

enemy_x = 0 #enemy x
enemy_y = 0 #enemy y
enemy_speed = 2 #enemy speed

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('Black')
wn.setup(width, height)

#collision
def check_collision():
    if player.distance(enemy) < 20:
        end()

#end game
def end():
        wn.bgcolor('white')
        pen.write("you touched a box", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
        alive = False


#player
player = Turtle()
player.penup()
player.shape('square')
player.color('blue')
player.penup()

#enemy
enemy = Turtle()
enemy.penup()
enemy.goto (0, 400)
enemy.pendown()
enemy.shape('square')
enemy.color('red')
enemy.penup()

#pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("black")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)

alive = True

#main loop

while alive == True:
    #player movment
    def p_up():
        check_collision()
        player_y = player.ycor()
        player_y += 20
        player.sety(player_y)

    def p_down():
       check_collision()
       player_y = player.ycor()
       player_y -= 20
       player.sety(player_y)

    def p_right():
        check_collision()
        player_x = player.xcor()
        player_x += 20
        player.setx(player_x)

    def p_left():
        check_collision()
        player_x = player.xcor()
        player_x -= 20
        player.setx(player_x)

    #keyboard bindind
    player.penup()
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(p_up, 'Up')
    wn.onkeypress(p_down, 'Down')
    wn.onkeypress(p_right, 'Right')
    wn.onkeypress(p_left, 'Left')




    #bringing enemy to the top, and then to a random spot on the y axis 
    for i in range (1, 5):
        enemy.clone()
        enemy.hideturtle()
        enemy_x = random.randint(-300, 300)
        enemy_y = 300
        print(random)
        enemy.goto(enemy_x, enemy_y)
        enemy.showturtle()

    #ememy moving down
    for i in range (1, 300):
        #check if the player is touching the enemy
        check_collision()
        enemy_y = enemy.ycor()
        enemy_y -= enemy_speed
        enemy.sety(enemy_y)

    enemy.hideturtle()

    wn.update()
```

Comment: This `if p.distance(e or e2 or e3 or e4) < 20` is only checking the distance for `e`, not for the others. `(e or e2 or e3 or e4)` evaluates to `e`.

Comment: ... but then you don't seem to be declaring `e2` etc. anywhere, so I'm not sure how you imagine any of this working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess so there's no *simple fix* to your problems.  Specifically:

You attempt to create multiple enemies but your `check_collision()` function and motion code are only designed to handle a single enemy.

You do `e.clone()` but fail to save the result so this just litters the screen.  Turtles are effectively global entities that aren't garbage collected, so rather than clone new ones, reuse old ones.

The doubled `while` loops seem strange:

```
while alive == True:
    # ...

while True:
    wn.update()
```

In particular, `update()` doesn't make much sense unless `tracer()` has been throttled.  So this second loop effectively does nothing.

Infinite, or length of game, loops don't make sense in an event-driven world like turtle.  It makes more sense to use `screen.ontimer()`.

Here's my rewrite of your code that I believe does what you desire:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
FONT = ("Courier", 24, "normal")

# end game
def end():
    global alive

    screen.bgcolor('white')
    pen.write("You touched a box!", align="center", font=FONT)
    alive = False

    screen.update()

# collision
def check_collision():
    screen.update()

    for enemy in enemies:
        if player.distance(enemy) < 20:
            end()
            break

# player movement
def p_up():
    player.sety(player.ycor() + 20)
    check_collision()

def p_down():
    player.sety(player.ycor() - 20)
    check_collision()

def p_right():
    player.setx(player.xcor() + 20)
    check_collision()

def p_left():
    player.setx(player.xcor() - 20)
    check_collision()

# main loop
def move():

    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.ycor() < -300:
            enemy.hideturtle()
            enemy.goto(randint(-400, 400), 300)
            enemy.velocity = randint(4, 8)
            enemy.showturtle()
        else:
            enemy.sety(enemy.ycor() - enemy.velocity)

        check_collision()

        if not alive:
            break

    if alive:
        screen.ontimer(move, 50)

alive = True

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('Black')
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.tracer(False)

# player
player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.color('blue')
player.penup()

# enemy
enemy_prototype = Turtle()
enemy_prototype.hideturtle()
enemy_prototype.shape('square')
enemy_prototype.color('red')
enemy_prototype.penup()

enemies = []

for _ in range(3):
    enemy = enemy_prototype.clone()
    enemy.goto(randint(-400, 400), 300)
    enemy.velocity = randint(4, 8)
    enemy.showturtle()
    enemies.append(enemy)

# pen
pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.penup()
pen.sety(260)

# keyboard bindind
screen.onkeypress(p_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(p_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(p_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(p_left, 'Left')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```